# Pivot data from a MySQL result set

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pivot

MySQL database result set:

```
Department     Month      Value
Sale        February       50
Sale        March          35
Sale        April          65
Sale        May            120
Dispatch   February       85
Dispatch   March          23
Dispatch   April          45
Dispatch   May            33
.... etc
```

And this is repeated for all four departments.

I want PHP to format data result so this looks like this:

```
['Month',   'Sales',  'Dispatch',   'Support', 'Calibration'],
['February', 50,     85,         15,      53],
['March',    35,     23,         12,      55],
```

etc

MySQL statement:

```
$sql_line_chart = "SELECT d.department as department, MONTHNAME(date_created) AS month, 
               COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN c.cat_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15) THEN time_spent END), 0) as value
                FROM master AS m 
                 INNER JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id 
                  INNER JOIN department AS d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id 
                  WHERE 
                  AND 
                  date_created > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 DAY 
                 AND  
                date_created < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
               GROUP BY d.department, month 
              ORDER by d.department ASC, m.date_created ASC";
```

Comment: Have you tried some php yet? Show us that.

Comment: Please post the code of what you tried

Comment: Change your ORDER BY clause to month department and then parse the results in a simple PHP loop

Comment: $result = query($sql_line_chart);
            confirm_result($result);      
          
            
         while ($row = fetch_array($result)) {
            
            $table[] = array($row['month'], $row['down_time_spent']);
            
       }
 $jsontable = json_encode($table);

But this does not come out the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your data by iterating your query results and establish a new 2d array.

It is important to nominate keys for the new rows otherwise, values may be written in the wrong column.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R3p6g))

```
$columns = ['Sale', 'Dispatch', 'Support', 'Calibration'];
$columnLookup = array_flip($columns);
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $rowKey = $row['month'];
    $colKey = $columnLookup[$row['department']];
    $result[$rowKey][$colKey] = $row['value'];
}
```

Once you have `$result`, there will be many ways to present the data as HTML.  Here is a basic/simple way to loop and output the data without HTML:

```
foreach ($result as $month => $colVals) {
    printf(
        "%' 10s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
        $month,
        $colVals[0] ?? 0,
        $colVals[1] ?? 0,
        $colVals[2] ?? 0,
        $colVals[3] ?? 0
    );
}
```

Output:

```
  February  50  85  0   0
     March  35  23  0   0
     April  65  45  0   0
       May  120 33  0   0
```